# HDMI on Nouveau driver is glitchy

Tags: xorg, nvidia, hdmi, nouveau

I am trying to use HDMI with a nVidia GT525M card with the Nouveau driver. Distro is Ubuntu 15.04 and the monitor works perfectly with the VGA output (by a Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter) - then I know the monitor is not the problem.

Kernel is 3.19.0. Package versions are:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nouv
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:amd64                                2.4.60-2                                   amd64        Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:i386                                 2.4.60-2                                   i386         Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                           1:1.0.11-1ubuntu2build1                    amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
```

However, I am getting lots of graphics glitches, like this one that happens when I move the mouse around:

[image]

It happens regardless of the window manager/desktop in use (I tried in Unity, MATE and XFCE). What can be wrong?